# Calculating Sum of 2D Array(Table) in LUA

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua, sum

I was just wondering how to calculate the sum of the components within a 2D array or table in lua. I've tried searching but there doesn't seem to be any clear or simple way of doing it.

I have a 5x5 Matrix that have randomly generated cells and i was looking to know the sum of these values at a given time.

Is there anything built into lua such as sum(matrix) or sumof(matrix[][]).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lua isn't Matlab or Python - There are very, very few standard libraries. Lua tables can do a good job of approximating most objects (including matrices) and it's designed to be easy to link in libraries written in C. If you want to do a lot of matrix work, the Lua way is to write your own or use a 3rd-party library like [NumLua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/) or [LuaMatrix](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaMatrix).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> there anything built into lua such as sum(matrix) or sumof(matrix[][]).

No. Just iterate through the elements and add:

```
local sum = 0
for ir,row in pairs(matrix) do
  for ic,col in pairs(row) do
    sum = sum + col
  end
end
```