# How do I get the sum of 2 tables in LUA?

Tags: lua, sum

```
x = {1, 2, 3}
y = {4, 5, 6}
z = x + y
```

I have two tables x and y and just want to create a third one which is just the sum of elements in them. I use the above LUA code in an effort but this gives error input:3: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (global 'x')...

Like, I want the result `z = {5, 7, 9}`

Please suggest functions that will be helpful, or please help me form such a function in LUA.
Thanks

Comment: You have to do it in the obvious way: iterate over the tables and add their components individually, storing them in an output table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating Sum of 2D Array(Table) in LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647737/calculating-sum-of-2d-arraytable-in-lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iterate and check with `table.concat()`
do...

```
x = {1, 2, 3}
y = {4, 5, 6}
z = {}

-- First check same table length and if so then add sums to z table
if #x==#y then
for i=1,#x do
 z[i]=x[i]+y[i]
end
end

print(table.concat(z,' '))
-- puts out: 5 7 9
```

...end

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add tables in Lua unless you implement the `__add` metamethod.

For an element wise sum of two sequences simply do this:

```
function sumElements(t1,t2)
  local result = {}
  for i = 1, math.min(#t1, #t2) do
    result[i] = t1[i] + t2[i]
  end
  return result
end
```

of course you should verify your inputs and think about how you want to deal with mismatching table sizes. Let's say t1 has 3 elements and t2 has 5, will you just have 3 result values or will you add 0 to the remaining 2?